# Android - I got "you must supply a resource id for a textview" even it's filled

Tags: android, textview, navigation-drawer

I'm using a NavigationDrawer, with simple textview on each menu, and wanted to add an icon left of my menus, so I add put this :

drawer_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity (part) :

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;

    // Google Map
    private static GoogleMap MainGoogleMap;
    private static String SelectedMenuPosition;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_array);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
                ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.map, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
         // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action buttons
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_websearch:
            // create intent to perform web search for this planet
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
            intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
            // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* The click listner for ListView in the navigation drawer */
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }
```

activity_main.xml

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
         space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. A solid background is used for contrast
         with the content view. -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

logcat :

```
04-27 17:14:52.327: E/ArrayAdapter(1353): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
04-27 17:14:52.337: D/AndroidRuntime(1353): Shutting down VM
04-27 17:14:52.337: W/dalvikvm(1353): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:767)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353):     ... 33 more
```

but I got this error you must supply a resource id for a textview :/

Do you have any idea please ?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Use `android:id="@+id/text1"` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but Still have the same error !

Comment: a Project/Clean should fix it.

Comment: I already clean the project put android:id="@+id/text1", but nothing changes :/

Comment: Post the code in ques.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916459/you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textview-android-error

Comment: Code posted (some parts)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue. Answer given here worked for me: [You must supply a resource ID for a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437196/you-must-supply-a-resource-id-for-a-textview)

for custom layout, make only a TextView xml file. and in your MainActivity.java file, pass the TextView id as well in the ArrayAdapter parameter list. In your case:

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, **R.id.text1**, mPlanetTitles));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with

```
 mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                R.layout.drawer_list_item, mPlanetTitles));
```

Your are going to set **ArrayAdapter** of string then the layout should contain only **textview** in your **drawer_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

If you want textview with images then create custom Adapter.

So that's why Exception comes

```
04-27 17:14:52.327: E/ArrayAdapter(1353): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
04-27 17:14:52.357: E/AndroidRuntime(1353): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
```

**drawer_list_item.xml** parent layout is relative and adapter required only textview

Comment: Code posted (some parts)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired functionality by adding the following attribute available to the [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft).
android:drawableLeft

Comment: which following attributes please ?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use simple array adapter use this code

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mPlanetTitles));
```

using existing code use this code below but image will not be set

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.text1, mPlanetTitles));
```

but if you want imageview also write custom adapter.